# Jekyll site not rendering markdown

Tags: markdown, jekyll, github-pages

I have an issue where my remote repository is updated, but my Github pages site will not update. The content of http://balassit.github.io/readings/GitNotes.md is outdated. I have verified that in my settings of Github my site builds from master. The content on master is up to date with my local branch.

I have run my site locally using `jekyll build` and `jekyll serve`. This produces the expected output on localhost:4000.

I have seen posts about markdown being an issue rendering in jekyll pages because of kramdown formatting, but that does not appear to be the issue for me.

https://github.com/balassit/balassit.github.io/tree/master

GitNotes.html YAML Block

```
---
layout: markdown
title: "Readings"
id: "readings"
custom_css: readings/github-markdown.css
---
```

github-markdown.css is from https://github.com/sindresorhus/github-markdown-css/blob/gh-pages/github-markdown.css

head.html

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/css/main.css">

<!-- Custom CSS and JavaScript -->

{% for css_file in page.custom_css %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/{{ css_file }}">
{% endfor %}

{% for js_file in page.custom_js %}
<script src="{{ site.baseurl }}/{{ js_file }}"></script>
{% endfor %}

{% for js_file in page.source_js %}
<script src="{{ js_file }}"></script>
{% endfor %}

<title>{{ page.title }}</title>
</head>
```

markdown.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
{% include head.html %}

<body>
    <style>
    .markdown-body {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        min-width: 200px;
        max-width: 1080px;
        padding: 45px;
    }
    </style>
    {% include header.html %}

    {% include sidebar.html %}

    <main>
        <article class="markdown-body">
            <markdown>
                {{ content }}
            </markdown>
        </article>
    </main>
    {% include footer.html %}
    <script src="https://spikespaz.github.io/tagdownjs/scripts/tagdown.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The bottom script is for tagdown, which can be seen at http://spikespaz.com/tagdownjs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GitNotes.md` does not have the YAML Front Matter but `GitNotes.html` does. Why two files with same `filename`?

Adding Front Matter to `GitNotes.md` will process it to `_site/GitNotes.html`

Comment: I used the GitNotes.md as the original file when I was working. That is the reason for the same naming. I just deleted it and it worked. Thanks for the help. Why would the two files conflict?

Comment: They would conflict each other only if they both contain Front matter but don't have different `permalink` definitions. In that case, they both will be processed into `_site/GitNotes.html`, one overwriting the other. If they both dont have front matter, the one without frontmatter will only be copied verbatim to `_site` without being processed.

Comment: P.S. If the answer resolves your issue completely, you need to accept it to mark this issue as solved